# io.realm.PermissionManager is not recognized

Tags: android, realm

I am developing a shared shopping list application where an user can share his/her list with the family members. I am using **Realm Object Server** as a database to store all the lists and users. To grant the read permission to the other users (aka family members), I decided to use **Full-Sync permissons** and I found the following code snippet in appropriate Realm docs. But the problem is **io.realm.PermissionManager** class is not recognized in my project.

```
PermissionManager pm = user.getPermissionManager();

// Create request
UserCondition condition = UserCondition.username(username);
AccessLevel accessLevel = AccessLevel.WRITE;
PermissionRequest request = new PermissionRequest(condition, url, accessLevel);

pm.applyPermissions(request, new PermissionManager.ApplyPermissionsCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onSucesss() {
        // Permissions where succesfully changed
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(ObjectServerError error) {
        // Something went wrong
    }
});
```

To install Realm in my project I did the following step:

1. adding  `classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:6.0.1"` to project level build.gradle file
2. applying `plugin: 'realm-android'` to application level build.gradle file

Do I miss something to insert io.realm.PermissionManager to my project?

Comment: for me it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In current realm api class PermissionsManager does not exist. I checked it here:
https://realm.io/docs/java/6.0.1/api/overview-summary.html

Maybe you're using some example with old api?

More information you cand find in changelog of realm:
https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

In version 6.0.0 there was a breaking change with PermissionManager.